# Use rpi for local only intranet

Tags: dhcp, access-point

We're going on a trip, and I want to set up a car only lan so that the kids can play games together on their tablets or maybe access a media shared volume.

There won't be any internet access.

Is this something I can do with just a pi, or do I need to get a travel router like a TP Link N300 to make it work?

Comment: There are 210 questions tagged access-point. Have you tried?

Comment: @Milliways Yes. Do you feel mine is a duplicate? Might be I overlooked one that was close to what I am trying to figure out, or possibly I don't know enough to be asking the right question. Your comment doesn't solve either of those problems.

Comment: I was trying to suggest possible solutions - there are many linked Answers. I have used some in the past. There are 2 main approached `hostapd` and `systemd` and a Raspberry Pi Ltd. tutorial - pick 1 and try it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tutorial describes how to setup a stand alone **Access Point** using `systemd-networkd`.

Configuring networking using `systemd-networkd` requires multiple steps, and it is easy to get things wrong.
The following scripts simplify the process and enables swapping between Access Point and normal networking.
*There are other tutorials which offer additional features and/or automatic detection but at the expense of additional complexity.*

**Before** running the scripts below follow the [Simplified Systemd-Networkd setup](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/117843/8697) and verify that networking is working as before.

*I have changed most of my Pi to *Systemd-Networkd* and this offers similar functionality to the `dhcpcd` setup (except this will disable the Networking tool on the Desktop Panel).*

- Step1 installs necessary files.
- The second script activates the Access Point.

Reboot REQUIRED!
**All script MUST be run by root or with sudo**.

This should result in an Access Point **RaspberryPiNet** @ address 10.1.4.1
If you have Ethernet this should continue to operate as before except static IP Addresses will require different settings.

### SetupAccessPoint.sh

```
#! /bin/sh
# Script to install files for stand alone Access Point using systemd-networkd
# NOTE this does NOT swap networking systems - see separate script to activate
# This script MUST be run by root or with sudo
# 2022-07-20

echo "Install files for stand alone Access Point using systemd-networkd"
echo "Before use change country & psk"
echo "This setup for Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)"

if [ `whoami` != root ]; then
    echo "This script MUST be run by root or with sudo"
    exit
fi

# Setup wpa_supplicant as Access Point
cat > /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf <<EOF
country=AU
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="RaspberryPiNet"
    mode=2
    frequency=2412
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    proto=RSN WPA
    psk="PASSWORD"
}
EOF

# Create a network configuration for Access Point
cat > /etc/systemd/network/03-wlan0.network <<EOF
[Match]
Name=wlan0

[Network]
Address=10.1.4.1/24
DHCPServer=yes
MulticastDNS=yes
EOF
```

### ActivateAccessPoint.sh

```
#! /bin/sh
# Script to Activate Access Point using systemd-networkd
# Assumes network configuration files and wpa_supplicant.conf file have been setup
# This script MUST be run by root or with sudo
# Reboot REQUIRED!

# 2022-07-20

echo "Activate Access Point using systemd-networkd"

if [ `whoami` != root ]; then
    echo "This script MUST be run by root or with sudo"
    exit
fi

rm /etc/systemd/network/03-wlan.network
systemctl enable systemd-networkd
systemctl enable wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service
```

To revert to normal networkin re-run the the [Simplified Systemd-Networkd setup](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/117843/8697) procedure.