# How to connect to rpi 4 without home network via Wifi adapter

Tags: wifi, ssh, ubuntu

I have a Rpi 4 (Ubuntu 20.04.5) and a desktop (Windows 11).
On the desktop, I have a wifi adapter.
How can connect to RPI via ssh without wifi home network? I don't need the RPI to have access to the internet.

Comment: What do you mean by "wifi adaptor?"

Comment: If the adapter you have is a cable modem/router, you  can (usually) run an Ethernet cable between the router and the pi. This usually doesn't involve much setup and is probably the easiest thing to do. Your computers can just use the router's wifi. If I'm wrong about the router, then in the immortal words of Emily L., "Never mind."

Answer (score 0):

The normal solution is to configure the Pi as an Access Point.

There are many tutorials using different networking tools for Raspberry Pi OS or Raspbian.

One solution using systemd-networkd https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/138392/8697 This would work on Ubuntu but obviously needs change for different networking tools.

It would be possible for Ubuntu but you are unlikely to find an answer on this site as Ubuntu usually uses NetworkManager.