# Connect to the raspberry pi over SSH when using the raspberry as a hotspot

Tags: ssh, access-point, modem

I configured my raspberry pi as an access point and I connected my laptop to the wifi network of the pi. However I was not able to reach the pi
`PING : 56 data bytes ping: sendto: No route to host Request timeout for icmp_seq 0 ping: sendto: No route to host Request timeout for icmp_seq 1`
I tried multiple configurations and even end up using raspAP but the result remained the same.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What happens if you connect to the ethernet address?

Comment: "I configured my raspberry pi as an access point" How? What does ip a and ip r show? How are you trying to connect?

Comment: @Milliways I tried something else : I followed the tutorial https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/95072/access-point-as-wifi-router-repeater-with-additional-wifi-dongle with wlan1 as access point and wlan0 as client

Comment: But the access point doesn't seems to be created

Comment: ip a : ``3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000     link/ether e4:xx brd ff:xx     inet 10.23.161.2/23 brd 10.23.161.255 scope global dynamic wlan0        valid_lft 1209266sec preferred_lft 1209266sec     inet6 fe80::e65f:1ff:fe1b:d206/64 scope link         valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever``

Comment: ``4: wlan1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000     link/ether 90:xx brd ff:xx 5: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000     link/ether 4a:xx brd ff:xx``

Comment: ip r : ``ip r : default via 10.23.160.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 10.23.161.2 metric 1024  10.23.160.0/23 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 10.23.161.2  10.23.160.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp scope link src 10.23.161.2 metric 1024  169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 169.254.0.0 ``

Comment: DO NOT put detail in Comments EDIT your Question

Answer (score 0):

The post by Ingo should work (*if you followed it*) but I find his posts difficult to replicate and developed a simplified method to setup a
[Stand Alone Access Point](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/138392/8697)

It is not entirely clear what you are trying to do.
One thing however, if using multiple interfaces the results are unpredictable unless you use Predictable Network Interface Names or write your own udev rules.

The on-board WiFi will normally be `wlan0`, but there is a potential race condition.

If you want to use 2 wireless interfaces I suggest you `Enable predictable network i/f names` in the `Advanced` option of `raspi_config`.

Your other interfaces will then have names like `wlx00c140123456`

See **Predictable Network Interface Names** in [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Comment: Thank you. I think I followed the steps of the post (except that I used nano rather than cat > ... <<EOF to edit the files). I'm trying to create an access point with a USB dongle (I don't really need internet connexion because the network will be used to stream video from the pi)